# Oracle Apex 5.1 Interactive grid save issue

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have an interactive grid that intermittently fails to save changed data properly.

I have a changed the default save process into a PL/SQL process to allow me to do some lookups before the data is saved back to the table. I have some PL/SQL logging in the save procedure, so I can see when the process starts & ends and what a number of the variable values are.

This process works fine, most of the time. However every now and again 1 in 20 or so, the process fires but I can see that one of the new values is actually the old value, so the update works with the wrong data. I can not see any pattern to how I'm updating the cell when it doesn't work.

I have created a button with a dynamic action to Submit the page on button click, which fires the update whenever a change is made. I also have a branch on the button at "After Processing".

I'm not sure the branch is relevant as I can see that the save procedure fires before it's redirected, but sometimes without using the updated values.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to track down my issue?

Cheers
Pav

Comment: Did you try to run that page in debug mode and see what debug info says?

Answer (score 0):

The debug didn't show anything. However I believe I found the cause.

The page had some javascript lifted from the IG Cookbook to calculate a column total.
When I removed one command it stopped the issue. I also tracked the issue to a model change that wasn't saved, then navigated off page and then back. Then the first changed made and saved would save original value and not the changed value.

Code removed was:
// just in case fetch all the data. Model notifications will
// cause calls to update so nothing to do in the callback function.
// can remove if data will always be less than 50 records
model.fetchAll(function() {});
Cheers
Pav